# Program glitches out after a few seconds (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program that should display some data that's going over a CanBus (data is being refreshed every 200ms), however when I make an objects from my class like this:

```
batteryDegree = PlaceInfo(root,img='battery.png',fotox=0.23,fotoy=0.35,foto_y_resize=180,foto_x_resize=180,anchor='center', text="100*C",textx=0.23,texty=0.38,canid=0x1000400,byte=2,size=30)
motorDegree = PlaceInfo(root,img='motor.png',fotox=0.75,fotoy=0.35,foto_y_resize=200,foto_x_resize=200,anchor='center', text="100*C",textx=0.76,texty=0.37,canid=0x1000400,byte=0,size=30)
```

Here is my class:

```
bus = can.interface.Bus(channel='can0')
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x480")
root.config(bg='red')
canvas = Canvas(root,width=800,height=480,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack() 
class PlaceInfo():
    def __init__(self,root, **kwargs):     
        self.root = root  
        if 'img' in kwargs:
            if 'foto_x_resize' in kwargs and 'foto_y_resize' in kwargs:
                self.png = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('imgs/' + kwargs['img']).resize((kwargs['foto_x_resize'],kwargs['foto_y_resize']),Image.ANTIALIAS))
            else:
                self.png = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('imgs/' + kwargs['img']))
            self.image = canvas.create_image(800 * kwargs['fotox'],480 * kwargs['fotoy'] ,image=self.png,anchor='center') 

        
        if 'text' in kwargs:
            self.text = canvas.create_text(kwargs['textx'] * 800, 
                                            kwargs['texty'] * 480,
                                            text=kwargs['text'],
                                            fil=kwargs['kleur'] if 'kleur' in kwargs else 'white',
                                            font=('arial',kwargs['size'] if 'size' in kwargs else 10))
                                            
        if 'canid' in kwargs and 'index' not in kwargs:
            self.changeData(kwargs['canid'], kwargs['byte'],kwargs['textx'], kwargs['texty'],kwargs['size'])

        elif 'canid' in kwargs and 'index' in kwargs:
            self.changeDataWithIndex(kwargs['canid'], kwargs['byte'],kwargs['textx'], kwargs['texty'],kwargs['size'],kwargs['index'])
    
    def changeData(self,canid,byte,textx,texty,size):
        try:
            msg = bus.recv(1)
            canvas.delete(self.text)
            if msg.arbitration_id == canid:
                self.data = msg.data[byte]
                self.text = canvas.create_text(textx * 800, 
                                                texty * 480,
                                                text=str(self.data),
                                                fill='white',
                                                font=('arial',size))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        self.root.after(250,lambda: self.changeData(canid,byte,textx,texty,size))
```

The program works for a few seconds but breaks after, what I mean is that it just stops displaying data and when I move my window around the colors are all over the place.
(When I print something in my functions it still prints)

Comment: You create new text item in the canvas whenever `changeData()` is called.  You should update the text item using `canvas.itemconfigure(self.text, ...)` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 i thought that that might be the problem and changed it but it still does the same :\

Comment: Try reducing the timeout of recv() or running `changeData()` in thread.

Comment: @acw1668 i have tried multi threading but the problem is that ```changeData()``` gets called every 250ms for EVERY object

Comment: I think you have design fault.  Multiple tasks reading *same* channel may cause race condition.  Also task A may read the message for task B and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have more than one instance of `PlaceInfo`, therefore there is more than one after task reading the CanBus which may cause race condition.  Also after task A may read the message for task B and vice versa.

You need to centralize the reading of the CanBus and perform the reading in a thread because `recv()` is a blocking task.

So you can create a `CanReader` class which extends from `threading.Thread` and call `recv()` in its `run()` function:

```py
from threading import Thread
from queue import SimpleQueue

class CanReader(Thread):
    def __init__(self, channel):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self._bus = can.interface.Bus(channel=channel)
        self._queues = {}

    def register(self, canid):
        if canid not in self._queues:
            self._queues[canid] = []
        queue = SimpleQueue()
        self._queues[canid].append(queue)
        return queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            msg = self._bus.recv()
            for q in self._queues[msg.arbitration_id]:
                q.put(msg)
```

Then you can create an instance of `CanReader` as below:

```py
bus = CanReader('can0')
bus.start()
```

`CanReader` provides a function `register()` for `PlaceInfo` to register and get a `SimpleQueue` object holding the messages received by `CanReader`.

Below is modified `PlaceInfo`:

```py
class PlaceInfo():
    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):     
        self.root = root  
        img = kwargs.get('img', None)
        if img:
            image = Image.open('images/'+img)
            foto_x_resize, foto_y_resize = kwargs.get('foto_x_resize'), kwargs.get('foto_y_resize')
            if foto_x_resize and foto_y_resize:
                image = image.resize((foto_x_resize, foto_y_resize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.png = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            self.image = canvas.create_image(800*kwargs['fotox'], 480*kwargs['fotoy'], image=self.png, anchor='center') 

        textx = kwargs.get('textx', None)
        texty = kwargs.get('texty', None)
        fill = kwargs.get('kleur', 'white')
        size = kwargs.get('size', 10)
        text = kwargs.get('text', None)
        if text:
            self.text = canvas.create_text(textx*800, texty*480, text=text, fill=fill, font=('arial',size))

        canid = kwargs.get('canid', None)
        if canid:
            self.queue = bus.register(canid) # register to CanReader using canid
            if 'index' not in kwargs:
                self.changeData(canid, kwargs['byte'])
            else:
                self.changeDataWithIndex(canid, kwargs['byte'], kwargs['index'])
    
    def changeData(self, canid, byte):
        try:
            msg = self.queue.get_nowait() # read message
            self.data = msg.data[byte]
            canvas.itemconfigure(self.text, text=str(self.data))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        self.root.after(250, self.changeData, canid, byte)
```

Hope this help you solve the issue.

Comment: complete error: ```Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/py/classes.py", line 36, in run
    for q in self._queues[hex(msg.arbitration_id)]:
KeyError: 1677820 ```

Comment: my bad, after refactoring my messy code it worked. thank you! could you explain how the run method is being ran? i dont know alot about threading

Comment: `run()` is the method of `Thread` class that will be executed when `start()` is called.